# Display xml content in iframe

Tags: javascript, html, xml, iframe

I want to display XML content in iFrame. I tried with html code below but it didn't work. It just show a blank page.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<iframe src="gui.xml" WIDTH="78%" HEIGHT="300">
  <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
</iframe>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Tried your code with a sample xml of mine and worked fine. Are you sure you are giving the right path to xml file? What you are including in your code means your xml is exactly in the same folder as your html file

Comment: I put xml file in same folder with html file.